# Единственное и множественное число

Tags: грамотная-речь, число, согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

Ему была вручена памятная медаль и подарки (или были вручены).

В мёде содержится 180 полезных питательных веществ, витаминов, макро и микроэлементов, протеинов, органических кислот (или содержатся).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ему были вручены памятная медаль и подарки.

Во втором предложении возможны обе формы.

В мёде содерж**и**тся 180 полезных питательных веществ, витаминов, макро- и микроэлементов, протеинов, органических кислот. - акцент на совокупности.

В мёде содерж**а**тся 180 полезных питательных веществ, витаминов, макро- и микроэлементов, протеинов, органических кислот. - акцент на каждом виде полезных веществ, каждый из перечня элементов содержимого важен.

Comment: Дроблёный на 18 частей акцент - уже не акцент. А здесь на порядок больше. Акцентирование уместно, но в отношении ингредиентов, допустим, в салате, а также - содержания кого-либо где-либо. Например: в изоляторе содержатся пятеро (задержанных). Т.е. содержания в смысле удержания и жизнеобеспечения, а не в смысле качества продукта при внешне однородной массе или среде.

Comment: Почему ж не акцент? Кому-то важно, что их много, целых 180, а кому - то важно, что там такой перечень, что отказаться невозможно,- и витамины, и протеины, и микроэлементы - всё, о чём последнее время так много говорят.

Comment: При всей любви к питательным веществам ещё раз прошу обратить внимание на текст: не "вещества содержатся", а "содержится 180, т.е. число". Подставлю для убедительности рядом стоящие величины, - содержится 181 вещество, содержится 182 вещества.

Comment: Неудачный пример: если числительное оканчивается на 1 и 2 - сказуемое всегда в ед. числе. Освежите память, правило:Имя числительное, в отличие от других имен, лишено признаков числа, если существительные могут иметь формы единственного и множественного числа (книга – книги), то числительные не имеют таких форм. По этой причине с числительным собственно «согласование» сказуемого по форме числа принципиально невозможно. Форма сказуемого единственного или множественного числа выбирается говорящим произвольно.

Comment: Форма ед.ч.сказуемого указывает на общую совокупность предметов, форма мн.ч.–на отдельные предметы: В республике строится пять стадионов (нерасчлененное представление о действии). – В крупнейших городах республики строятся ещё пять На постановку сказуемого в форму ед.ч. влияет стремление автора текста обратить внимание читателей на пассивность подлежащего, совместность действия действующих лиц, а также на количество, названное в подлежащем.
При употреблении множ.ч.-акцент на стремление автора обратить внимание на действие (характеристику), а не на количество. Так что множ.ч. тоже возможно.

Comment: Можно, но не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Подарки преподносятся, поэтому: вручена и преподнесены. В мёде содержится N число веществ, или содержатся вещества, но не наоборот.

Comment: Ценные подарки как награда тоже вручаются.

Comment: Не вижу препятствий. Правда, вручаются всё больше повестки, а подарки дарятся.